# ¿Cómo mover archivos por fechas a sus respectivas carpetas en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo varios archivos que tiene por nombre la fecha en día juliano. Ejemplo:

- 2014353_180000
- 2014353_190000
- 2014353_200000
- 2014354_180000
- 2014354_190000
- 2015355_190000
- 2015355_200000
- ...etc.

Lo que quiero es que de esos archivos pasarlos a su respectiva carpeta, como lo muestro a continuación.

```
.
├ 2014353/
|  ├─ 2014353_180000
|  ├─ 2014353_190000
|  └─ 2014353_200000
├ 2015354/
|  ├─ 2015354_190000
|  └─ 2015354_200000
etc ...
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?.

Comment: ¿Y cual es el criterio para decidir en qué carpeta van? Además, para que tu pregunta esté completa debes incluir el código que has intentado hasta ahora para que podamos ver en qué has fallado y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no incluye código que no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a suponer que los ficheros que quieres mover son aquellos que empiezan por 7 caracteres siendo todos ellos cifras. De las cuales las cuatro primeras son el año y pueden ser cualesquiera. Y las 3 siguientes son el día y deben ser un día del 1 al 366.
Supongo que quieres crear carpetas con nombres de 7 caracteres para aquellos días para los que haya ficheros y mover los ficheros de esos días a sus directorios.

```
from os import listdir, makedirs
from os.path import isfile, join, exists
from shutil import move

def esFecha( nombre ):
  if ( len(nombre)<7 ):
    return False
  if ( not nombre[0:7].isdigit() ):
    return False
  dia = int( nombre[4:7] )
  return dia>=1 and dia<=366

def moverFichero( nombre, dirBase ):
  directorio = nombre[0:7]
  destino = join( dirBase, directorio)
  if ( not exists(destino) ):
    makedirs(destino)
  origen = join( dirBase, nombre )
  move ( origen, destino )

dirBase='/home/test/py'
ficheros = [ f for f in listdir(dirBase) if isfile(join(dirBase,f)) ]
for fich in ficheros:
  if ( esFecha( fich ) ):
    moverFichero( fich, dirBase )
```

Como puedes ver primero creo una lista con todos los ficheros en el directorio `dirBase`.
Los cuales recorro en un bucle y para cada uno `esFecha` determina si el nombre de fichero se ajusta al criterio que he definido y si es así `moverFichero` crea el directorio si hace falta y mueve el fichero.

No está todo el trabajo hecho. Has de modificar `esFecha` para que tenga en cuenta los años bisiestos. O para que se ajuste a tu criterio si es diferente. Pero esto debiera encaminarte en la dirección correcta.